# why does date_parse always returning january 1st

Tags: php

I'm using `date_parse()` but I keep getting that the date is 1/1 while the other parameter such as the hour are fine.
Here is my code:

```
    $date = date('Y-d-n h:i:s');    
    echo "date: " .$date."\n";

    $parsedDate = date_parse($date);
```

The `echo` in the second line is returning something like:
`date: 2014-13-2 03:44:27`
But in `$parsedDate` these are the values:
`{"year":2014,"month":1,"day":1,"hour":3,"minute":44,"second":27}`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Y-d-n` is an extremely unusual date format, certainly nothing I'd expect any function to just magically understand.

Comment: You're right, when I changed it to `Y-n-d` it was solved.

Comment: The date must be in a format so [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) accepts it.

Comment: Please don't add [solved] or the solution in your question. That is what the answer section is for and the "accept answer" checkmark.

Comment: I clicked the checkmark, it told me I can accept an answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your data format from `'Y-d-n h:i:s'` to `'Y-n-d h:i:s'`